# How to disable background screen after alertdialog appear or enable only alertdialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a game after game over, I am save the score and name using alertdialog into database,its fine but when I click any where on game window alertdialog closed and again game is working for that I need disable game window after game is over or alertdialog never closed event I click on game window.

my code is:

```
mainactivity:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static TextView editText;
static int score=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
     editText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     //editText.setText(""+score);
     Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new AnimatedView(MainActivity.this).pauseClicked();
        }
    });
}
public static void setCount(int count) {

    //new MainActivity().onCreate(null);
    score=count;
    editText.setText(""+score);
}
```

Animatedview:

```
public class AnimatedView extends ImageView{

String name;
static int count=0;
private Context mContext;
int x = 130;
int y = 450;
private float a,b;
private int xVelocity = 20;
private int yVelocity = 20;
private Handler h;
private final int FRAME_RATE = 25;
BitmapDrawable ball;
boolean touching;
boolean dm_touched = false;
float move=3;
int bm_x = 0, bm_y = 0, bm_offsetx, bm_offsety,bm_w,bm_h;
boolean paused;
private Paint line, ball1, background;
static int click=0;
private static final int TEXT_ID = 0;
DBCeation dbCeation;
public AnimatedView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {  
    super(context, attrs);  
    mContext = context; 
    h = new Handler();
} 

private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Log.e("game","run called");
        if(touching = true)
        invalidate(); 
    }
};


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {  
    BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball);  
    if (x<0 && y <0) {
        //x = this.getWidth()/2;
        y = c.getHeight()/2;


    } else {
        //Log.d("s",""+xVelocity);
        Log.d("s",""+yVelocity);
        x += xVelocity;
        y += yVelocity;
        if ((x > this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
            xVelocity = xVelocity*-1;
        }
        if (y >( this.getHeight() - ball.getBitmap().getHeight()) ||y <0) {
            yVelocity = yVelocity*-1;
        }
    }
    c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);  
   //Log.e("sarat",""+touching);

  if(click>=2){
  if(bm_h+y>630){

       final EditText input=new EditText(mContext);
      Toast.makeText(getContext(),"game over",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
      builder.setTitle("Game Is Over");
        builder.setMessage("Enter your Name");
         // Use an EditText view to get user input.
         input.setId(TEXT_ID);
         builder.setView(input);
         builder.setPositiveButton("save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                name=input.getText().toString();
                Log.d("name",""+name);
                int score=MainActivity.score;
                dbCeation=new DBCeation(mContext);
                dbCeation.insertValues(name, score);
                Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,Home.class);
                click=0;
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
      builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);


      builder.show();
      x=150;
      y=200;
      xVelocity=0;
      yVelocity=0;

  }}
    if(touching){
         // Log.e("game","iftouch called called");
        h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);    
        bm_w=ball.getBitmap().getWidth();
        bm_h=ball.getBitmap().getHeight();
      }
  }
public void pauseClicked()
{   
    xVelocity=0;
    yVelocity=0;
    invalidate(xVelocity, yVelocity, 0, 0);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Log.d("game","ontouch called");
    int touchType = event.getAction();

     switch(touchType){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
            a = event.getX();
            b = event.getY();
            touching = true;

           /* if (dm_touched) {
                x = (int) a - bm_offsetx;
                y = (int) b - bm_offsety;
            }*/
            //invalidate();
            break;

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
             //x and y give you your touch coordinates
              a = event.getX();
              b = event.getY();
              touching = true;
              if(a>x+20&&a<330&&b<=y+320&&b>y){
                     click++;
                     Log.d("click",""+click);
                 invalidate();
                 touching=true;}
             /* if (touching) {
                    // paused = true;
                    h.removeCallbacks(r);
                    touching = false;
                } else {
                    touching = true;
                }*/
              //Log.d("game","action_down called");
              Log.e("s",""+ a);
              Log.e("s",""+ b);
              Log.e("s",""+ x);
              Log.e("s",""+ y);
              Log.e("s",""+ bm_w);
              Log.e("s",""+ bm_h);
              if ((a > x) && (a < bm_w + x) && (b > y) && (b < bm_h + y)) { 
                  count++;
                MainActivity.setCount(count);
                  //invalidate();
                  Log.i("score",""+count);

                }
              if (dm_touched) {
                  if ((a > x) && (a < bm_w + x) && (b > y) && (b < bm_h + y)) { 
                  move+=2;
                    //x = (int) a - bm_offsetx;
                  y = (int) (yVelocity*-1);

                  //invalidate();

                }}
               // dm_touched = true;
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             a = event.getX();
              b = event.getY();
            /* if(a>x+20&&a<330&&b<=y+320&&b>y){
                 click++;
                 Log.d("click",""+click);
             invalidate();
             touching=true;}*/
             if ((a > x) && (a < bm_w + x) && (b > y) && (b < bm_h + y)) { 
                Log.e("game","clicked");
            }

            default:

                dm_touched = true;
            }

            return true;
}

@Override
public void destroyDrawingCache() {

    count=0;
    click=0;
    super.destroyDrawingCache();
}
```

}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use its cancallable method like below,

```
builder.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: thanku friend,i have another question that is if u see my code the ball  is moving on screen in all directions, i want to pause the ball when i click button

Comment: first thing first, You have asked 21 question. But I think you are not aware of accepting an answer. Whenever an answer is helpful for you. You need to select the most suitable answer by ticking the green tick mark besides that answer.

Comment: really i am not aware tick mark just i am voted the answer,sorry for that

Comment: what about my question

Comment: @bharat It's ok friend. Now back to your question. On clicking of button set touching to false and see what happens.

Comment: actually i use activity for button so i have to control the ball from activity ,and i updated the code in my question, refer this link the image of game is uploaded [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523814/how-to-pause-the-ball-when-i-click-pause-button]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` method of `AlertDialog` if you want to prevent the `AlertDialog` from closing on window click but still want to be able to close it on back button click.